# How to get the last item in an array of objects where the value to a key has a specific character?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key-value

With the following array:

```
arrOfOranges =
[{ "kerp": "thisThing", "time": "@ rocks 3"},
{ "kerp": "otherThing", "green": "blah"},
{ "kerp": "thisThing", "time": "(countriesToTheStart ^"},
{ "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": "row row"},
{ "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": "rigorous"},
{ "kerp": "thisThing", "time": ",,,,"}]
```

Each item has the following permanent structure:

[{kerp: ''}] which can be one of 3 values: thisThing, otherThing and anotherThing. And the other key for each object depends on the value of 'kerp'.

If kerp: 'thisThing' then the other key is 'time'.     => { "kerp": "thisThing", "time": ""},

If kerp: 'otherThing' then the other key is 'green'.   => { "kerp": "otherThing", "green": ""},

If kerp: 'anotherThing' then the other key is 'yellow'.  =>    { "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": ""},

I want to get the last item in the array with 'kerp': 'thisThing'. However, the associated value of the 'time' key must contain a letter.

For example in the above array the last item in the array has 'kerp': 'thisThing', however 'time' does not contain a letter.

So I need to get this item from arrOfOranges where it's the last item in the array with kerp: thisThing and time with letters in the value:

```
{"kerp": "thisThing", "time": "(countriesToTheStart ^"}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
if (arrOfOranges.filter(a=>a.kerp === "thisThing")) {
    // this is just a eay to check if the array contains letters
    if(arrOfOranges.time.match(/[\w]+/g))  {
        return arrOfOranges.slice(-1)[0];
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work as intended. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: `Object.values(arrOfOranges).reverse().filter(f => f.time && /[a-z]/i.test(f.time)).pop()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the check inside the filter.

```js
const arrOfOranges = [
  { "kerp": "thisThing", "time": "@ rocks 3"},
  { "kerp": "otherThing", "green": "blah"},
  { "kerp": "thisThing", "time": "(countriesToTheStart ^"},
  { "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": "row row"},
  { "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": "rigorous"},
  { "kerp": "thisThing", "time": ",,,,"}
 ]

const result = arrOfOranges.filter(orange => orange.kerp === "thisThing" && orange.time.match(/[\w]+/g));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse your `arrOfOranges` using `.reverse()` and then use `.find()` on that reversed array. The find method will return the first object that the callback returns `true` for. Below, I've made it return true for when the `time` key contains a word-character `\w` and when the `kerp` key is equal to `"thisThing"`. Note that I've used `.slice()` before calling `.reverse()`, as reverse will modify `arrOfOranges` in place, which can be prevented by making a copy of the array first:

```js
const arrOfOranges = [{ "kerp": "thisThing", "time": "@ rocks 3"}, { "kerp": "otherThing", "green": "blah"}, { "kerp": "thisThing", "time": "(countriesToTheStart ^"}, { "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": "row row"}, { "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": "rigorous"}, { "kerp": "thisThing", "time": ",,,,"}];

const search = {kerp: "thisThing", key: "time"};
const res = arrOfOranges.slice().reverse().find(
  obj => obj.kerp === search.kerp && /\w/.test(obj[search.key])
);

console.log(res);
```

If you need a slightly more efficient approach, you can use a standard for loop to iterate backwards through your array:

```js
const arrOfOranges = [{ "kerp": "thisThing", "time": "@ rocks 3"}, { "kerp": "otherThing", "green": "blah"}, { "kerp": "thisThing", "time": "(countriesToTheStart ^"}, { "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": "row row"}, { "kerp": "anotherThing", "yellow": "rigorous"}, { "kerp": "thisThing", "time": ",,,,"}];

const search = {kerp: "thisThing", key: "time"};
function findObj(data, search) {
  for(let i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const curr = data[i];
    if(curr.kerp === search.kerp && /\w/.test(curr[search.key]))
      return curr;
  }
}

console.log(findObj(arrOfOranges, search));
```